# Python SNMP scripting - IP MAC and switch ports for a list of Cisco switches' IPs

Tags: python

How to fetch the entire table 'IP<->MAC<->switch_port' from a list of IPs (IP1,IP2,...IPn), using a given community of SNMP? Thanks,
Jerome

Comment: Hi @JeromeB, could you please add more detail to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
import nmap
nm=nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan(hosts='192.168.1.0/24', arguments='-n -sP -PE -PA21,23,80,3389')
hosts_list = [(x, nm[x]['status']['state']) for x in nm.all_hosts()]
for host, status in hosts_list:
    print('{0}:{1}'.format(host, status))
```

nmap module can help with this , this will scan most common ports(21,80..)

if you don't have it installed use `pip install nmap`